# Views in Drupal 7. Grouping multiple values. Where are they?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Example in Drupal 6 http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/307/9486641711.png

I need it to display only one first picture.
Or view all starting from the second.

Answer (score 2):

I had to look where they hid this too. It is now in
 `Advanced Settings >> Query Settings >> Settings`

or `Avancerede indstillinger >> Query Settings >> indstillinger` for you.

Answer (score 0):

[views settings page http://grab.by/grabs/58fbd67634ddc5c1c8341541ce4120be.png](http://grab.by/grabs/58fbd67634ddc5c1c8341541ce4120be.png)

Comment: Thish only for elements of page. I am interested in how make the same for elements in filefield. Please look exemple in post.

Particulary I was solved this task:
Query settings: Settings --> Distinct

but it doesn`t solve the problem in specific range.

Comment: This question has been in the bug report module. At this point the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed in dev branch.